# HowTo insert text beside of the portrait in moderncv (casual style)?

Tags: moderncv, german

In the German Resumé we ought to insert personal details (see "Persönliche Angaben" in the picture below).
Since I have no other place left in my CV (`casual` style of `moderncv`), I would like to append it on the right of my picture. So it should appear as small text between the picture and the name.
How can I do this?

[image: Move Personal Details Up to the side of the portrait]

```
\documentclass[10pt,unicode,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{casual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.1cm}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}

\firstname{...}
\familyname{...}
\title{Master...}
\address{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}
\email{...}
%\social[linkedin]{nickname}
\extrainfo{Referenzkontakte und beglaubigte Zeugniskopien folgen bei Interesse.}
\photo[64pt][0.1pt]{portrait.jpg} 

\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={YOUR NAME},
  pdftitle={Lebenslauf | YOUR NAME},
  pdfsubject={tabellarischer Lebenslauf}
}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{Persönliche Angaben}
\section{Bildungsweg}

\section{Praktische Tätigkeiten}
\subsection{• Berufstätigkeit}
\subsection{• Berufsbezogene Praktika}
\subsection{• Wehrersatzdienst}

\section{Studienarbeiten}
\section{Auslandsaufenthalte und Kurse}
\section{Sprachen}
\section{EDV-Kenntnisse}
\section{Interessen}

\textit{"Übung macht den Meister." \newline \newline}

\cvline{}{Place, Date \newline \includegraphics[height=1cm]{signature.jpg}} 
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Exactly what information do you plan to add and in what position? To the right of the picture, above the name, flushed to the right margin, for example?

Comment: I must complete: Since the syntax was updated, you get a confusing error, because "makecvfooter" has to be replaced with "makecvfoot" 
! Undefined control sequence.\maketitle ->\recomputecvlengths \makecvfooter\newsbox .... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334765/footer-disappears-in-moderncv-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility: I defined a `\insertpersonalinformation` command allowing you to typeset information between the picture and the name; in the example I used a `minipage` to typeset the information, but you can use any formatting you want:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{casual}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\insertpersonalinformation#1{\def\@insertpersonalinformation{#1}}
% commands
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % ensure footer with personal information
  \makecvfooter%
  % optional picture
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
       \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
       \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
         \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
       {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}}%
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  % name
  \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
  \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
    %\raggedleft%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@insertpersonalinformation}}
      {\raggedleft}
      {\hspace*{10pt}{\personalinfofont\@insertpersonalinformation}\hfill}% alternate design: \MakeLowercase
    {\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}
  }
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
  % optional title
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]% \null is required as there is no box on the line after \\, so glue (and leaders) disappears; this is in contrast to after \par, where the next line starts with an indent box (even after \noindent).
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother

\def\personalinfofont{\normalfont\small}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\photo{picture}
\insertpersonalinformation{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}%<- adjust here
  \raggedright
  \textbf{Geburt} \\
 12. August, 1964, \textnormal{\textit{Berlin}} \\
  \textbf{Familienstand} \\
  verheiratet, 2 kinder \\
  \textbf{Eherman} \\
  Max Munstermann, \textnormal{\textit{Musterberuf}} \\
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But it should appear not above but left of the name. And it should be attached at the right edge of the portrait.

Comment: @gloschtla Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Wonderful! This overwhelmingly long definition helped in my case. Now I just need to make the text a bit smaller.

Comment: @gloschtla You can use `\def\personalinfofont{\normalfont\footenotesize}` or any other size switch.

Comment: I tested it - replaced "small" with "tiny" - and it became really tiny. Are there other sizes in between small and tiny? I also tried "8pt", but it's not accepted. Actually "small" is already perfect in my case. Thank you so much!

Comment: @gloschtla You can use `\def\personalinfofont{\normalfont\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont}` The first argument for `\fontsize` is the desired font size; the second argument is the value for baselineskip (usually 20% more than the first argument.)

Comment: "makefooter" now has to be replaced with "makefoot", because there is a new syntax: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334765/footer-disappears-in-moderncv-v2